# using JSON.parse in DocumentApp

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

It seems I can't parse a json file in a Document script despite it's possible via a DriveApp script.

Here is a reproducible example :

edit a json valid file and save it as a .txt file in your google drive :

```
{
    "text_prompts": {
        "0": [
            "beautiful painting of front head of a woman, renaissance style:9",
            "colorful:10"
        ]
    },
    "image_prompts": {},
    "clip_guidance_scale": 1000,
    "tv_scale": 0,
    "range_scale": 150,
    "sat_scale": 0,
    "cutn_batches": 4,
    "max_frames": 10000,
    "interp_spline": "Linear",
    "init_image": "drive/MyDrive/AI/Disco_Diffusion/init_images/patricienne.png",
    "init_scale": 15000
}
```

Notice the first "text_prompts" record. This is what I want to extract from the json file.
Obtain the hash ID of this file via its link and note it.

Now create a Google Apps Script :

```
const FICHIER_ID = HASH_ID_OF_THE_JSON_FILE
function statsfichier() {
  const fichier = DriveApp.getFileById(FICHIER_ID);
  let content = fichier.getBlob().getDataAsString();
  let json = JSON.parse(content);
  Logger.log(fichier.getName());
  Logger.log(content)
  Logger.log(json.text_prompts)
}
```

Validate it, and launch it.
You should obtain the "text_prompts" record of the json file in the logs, like this :

`10:12:08   Infos   {0=[beautiful painting of front head of a woman, renaissance style:9, colorful:10]}`

Now, create an empty document in your drive. Create an Apps Script in it as follows :

```
const UI = DocumentApp.getUi();

function onOpen() {
  UI.createMenu('DD')
    .addItem("proof by json", "prpjsn")
    .addToUi();
}
function prpjsn() {
  const ficID = HASH_ID_OF_THE_JSON_FILE;
  const fichier = DriveApp.getFileById(ficID);
  let content = fichier.getBlob().getDataAsString();
  let json = JSON.parse(content);
  let prompts = json.text_prompts;

  UI.alert(content); // this is ok, I obtain the json file content

  UI.alert(json); // [object Object]
  UI.alert(prompts); // [object Object]
  
  UI.alert(String(json)); // [object Object]
  UI.alert(String(prompts)); // [object Object]
}
```

Reload the document, launch the script via the document menu, validate the script, launch it again.

The first alert shows that the file is appropriately read, but **no json extraction follows.**

How to do it ?

Comment: UI is undefined

Comment: What  was the content of the original files?

Comment: UI was defined above, sorry : `const UI = DocumentApp.getUi();`the document itself is an empty document with just an arbitrary title.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect as the images?

Comment: Thank you for adding more information. From your additional information, I proposed a modification point as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question and that was not useful for your situation, I apologize.

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting SyntaxError: Unexpected token % in JSON at position 0.  So it's not returning valid JSON don't think it's a good idea

Answer (score 0):

I believe your current issue and your goal is as follows.

- You want to show the value of `text_prompts` in your JSON data. But, when your bottom script is used, `[object Object]` is shown. This is your current issue.
- In your goal, you want to show the value of `text_prompts` instead of `[object Object]`.

If my understanding is correct, how about the following modification?

I think that in your bottom script, `content` is the string value. But, `json` and `prompts` are an object. I think that this is the reason for your issue. In order to show the value with `UI.alert(value)`, how about the following modification? In this modification, the object is converted to the string value using `JSON.stringify()`.

#### From:

```
UI.alert(json); // [object Object]
UI.alert(prompts); // [object Object]
```

#### To:

```
UI.alert(JSON.stringify(json));
UI.alert(JSON.stringify(prompts));
```

#### Note:

- For example, if you want to show the value of `beautiful painting of front head of a woman, renaissance style:9`, you can also use `UI.alert(json.text_prompts["0"][0]);`.

#### Reference:

- [JSON.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

Comment: Awesome ! I was missing the next step in the reasoning: going backwards. Thanks.

Comment: @Etienne Jouin Nammalvar Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, from `Awesome ! I was missing the next step in the reasoning: going backwards. Thanks.` and the current situation, I cannot understand whether your issue was resolved. If my answer was not useful, I have to apologize. Can I ask you whether your issue was resolved?

Comment: Yes my issue was resolved and your answer was very useful, thank you